# Read Excel Sheet with PHPExcel And Create individual input for each column

Tags: phpexcel

I am able to read from a worksheet in excel with the cells having data, and also i am able to create a form, problem is the form created has all input with same name, so i cannot loop each input and to save in the database according to the table columns say dataset1, dataset2...... Data from excel on my browser shows this

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value="Extra Work"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value="Extra works Claimed (House-6)"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value="7500"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value="7500"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value="375"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value="7125"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value="0"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

suggestions on how to make it look like

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value="Extra Work"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset2[]" value="Extra works Claimed (House-6)"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset3[]" value="7500"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset4[]" value="7500"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset5[]" value="375"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset6[]" value="7125"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset7[]" value="0"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="dataset8[]" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Here is the code

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0);
              echo '<form name="forma" method="post" action="'.base_url().'contract/savesheet'.'">'; echo '<table border=1>' . "\n"; 
              foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                  echo '<tr>' . "\n"; $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                  $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); 
                  foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) { 
                      echo '<td><input type="text" name="dataset1[]" value="' . $cell->getCalculatedValue() . '"/></td>' . "\n"; }
                      echo '</tr>' . "\n"; } echo '</table>' . "\n"; echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />';
                      echo '</form>'; 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($cellIterator as $col => $cell) { 
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="dataset'. 
        $col .'[]" value="' . 
        $cell->getCalculatedValue() . 
        '"/></td>' . "\n"; 
}
```

Comment: maybe you could add an explanation also for your snippet.